# PHP: How to save multiple checkbox values instead of one

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, checkbox, custom-fields

I'm trying to edit a WordPress front end user form plugin so that it will write away multiple check box values (from one of my custom fields) in a single SQL record. I need to do this so my query search form can search for all values checked off. Right now, if a user checks off more than one option, only one single value is being stored. How can I adjust this PHP code so that every value checked will be stored?

```
 /**
 * Prints a checkbox field
 *
 * @param array $attr
 * @param int|null $post_id  */ 

   function checkbox( $attr, $post_id, $type ) {
    $selected = isset( $attr['selected'] ) ? $attr['selected'] : array();

    if ( $post_id ) {
        $selected = explode( self::$separator, $this->get_meta( $post_id, $attr['name'], $type, true ) );
    }
    ?>

    <div class="wpuf-fields">
        <span data-required="<?php echo $attr['required'] ?>" data-type="radio"></span>

        <?php
        if ( $attr['options'] && count( $attr['options'] ) > 0 ) {
            foreach ($attr['options'] as $option) {
                ?>

                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $attr['name']; ?>[]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $option ); ?>"<?php echo in_array( $option, $selected ) ? ' checked="checked"' : ''; ?> />
                    <?php echo $option; ?>
                </label>
                <?php
            }
        }
        ?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where's the code that actually does the saving?

Comment: Thanks for responding? But I'm not sure. Which file is normally responsible for this so I can search for it right fast. Would it be in the plugin itself or in my theme files?